# int(11) to Fixed num (8 charactors) uniq hash

Tags: php, hash, unique, uniqueidentifier

I have a issue the following:

1. user_id(int(10))
2. oerder_type(tinyint(1))

   convert from 1)+2) = int(11) to a hash

   [0-9a-z]{8}

Comment: Can you explain your question more clearly?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english. clearly I means convert int(11) to [0-9a-z]{8} unique charactors. ex) 12345678901 => a1b2c3d4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need a hash function for hash table lookup, I recommend using [Murmurhash](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/). 10^11 is between 2^36 and 2^37. Therefore, call a hash that generate 64-bit (Murmurhash2) or 128-bit (Murmurhash3) hash, and mod 10^11. Unlike simply converting bases, using hash function may generate conflicts, even it is highly (if not perfectly) uniformly distributed. However, you will get much better avalanche effect. [Here](http://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/avalanche) is its avalanche test result.

If Murmurhash is not possible, Jenkins [lookup](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/index.html) functions are also good. [Here](http://bretm.home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/7.html) is its avalanche test result.

If performance is not a problem, or it is required cryptographic secure, SHA-1 might be the best pick, which has much more wrappers in various languages. Do not use CRC32 (bad avalanche).

**EDIT**: If you need PHP hash function, here is a sample code

```
function my_hash($user_id, $order_type)
{
    // construct integer (10^11)
    $data = $user_id * 10 + $order_type;
    // convert decimal to raw binary string (at most 5 bytes)
    $hex = dechex($data);
    $binary = pack('H*', $hex);
    // hash binary string. Substitute 'sha1' with other algorithms listed in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php if needed
    $hash = hash('sha1', $binary);
    // output first 8 bytes
    return substr($hash, 0, 8);
}

echo my_hash(1234567890, 0);  // 199f4bc7
echo my_hash(1234567890, 1);  // f3706f03
```

Also, there is [PHP extension for Murmurhash2](http://sites.google.com/site/nonunnet/php/php_murmurhash). You can compile and install if you run PHP on Linux. Replace those Murmurhash2 files with Murmurhash3 might be even better.

Comment: Thank's for great answer. I have to read. but I'm using php5 if you could same tool in php I'm so happy .

Comment: It's is the code I wanted! thank you so much. but my env  php test.php
72307cb3
04cb0609
 the hash code are changed by env(OS or .. )

Comment: in my survay . the pack() funciton is broken on x86_64

Comment: I use `pack()` simply to minimize the input of the hash function. You can skip the `dechex` and `pack` steps and directly pass `(string) $data` to `hash()`. Remember, there may be collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trivial hash function because:

```
36^8      = 2821109907456
10^12 - 1 = 999999999999
```

The range of `[0-9a-z]{8}` is larger than `10^12 - 1`. The trivial hash function would be to convert your number from base 10 to base 36 and left padd with 0 to the required length.

As it was pointed out, this might not satisfy uniformity. However for a hash function uniformity is usually required to minimize the cost of collisions which do not exist in this case.

If that doesn't satisfy your requirements then you need to get more specific.

Comment: I agree that in this scenario the hash will not conflict. However, remember that there are two other properties for a good hash function: uniformly distributed and strictly avalanche. Simply converting bases will not satisfy these properties.

Comment: Mh, good point. Updated my answer a bit. Depending on the purpose it might still be a valid approach.